# Showing push notifications while using Airplay on iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I use airplay to test, demo and develop an iOS device, especially using push notifications. This is because although you can drag `.apns` files onto a simulator, simulators don't work with APNs.

In iOS 15, they've made macOS devices running Monterey able to connect as an Airplay receiver. You can show your iOS screen on macOS using Airplay. (previously you needed [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/)). However, **now** all push notifications seem to be hidden when airplay is being used.

When looking at the `Console.app`:

```
com.apple.pushLaunch.com.apple.mobilenotes:AC2295:[
    {name: ApplicationPolicy, policyWeight: 50.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{[pushDisallowed]: Required:1.00, Observed:0.00},]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
```

This happens consistently when Airplay is being used by the device, and immediately stops being a problem when Airplay is turned off. I don't have any "focus" modes enabled.

I tried quicktime player, but I just get a black screen when selecting the device. This method has always been very buggy.

**There seems to be no way to develop, test or demo push notifications without using another camera to record the iOS screen...**

---

PS: Even though macOS Monterey adds support as an airplay receiver, it is annoying to use compared to AirServer for a developer. The screen must be full screen, and all other screens go black except for the device screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same probs here, but I've played around iOS settings and got it sorted.
Try to set Settings/Notifications/Screenshare then enable notifications with the slider. That's all.

Greetz Tom

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Tom was faster ;)

I just stumbled upon the same problem. You might need to check the following setting on your iOS device:

Settings -> Notifications -> Screen Sharing -> check "Allow Notifications"

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953292/7365866. Edit: I wonder how both of you came to it at the same time. 

Comment: We both had a call a minute ago and discussed it together. It was Tom who found the solution and he also found your question here. We also agreed to answer your question here but there was a miscommunication between Tom and me ;)
My bad here. All credits to Tom!

Comment: Oh okay, great . Between you and me, you wrote your answer to be more readable for people in the future (*cough* better). You could even enhance it with GIF's or screenshots.

Comment: And again some one is faster than me :) Thanks for adding the screenshots. I was just on my way to upload them and saw, you already did it. I agree, with screenshots it is a way better help for the next ones stumbling upon the problem and finding this answer.

Comment: I think the only reasonable way to resolve this is to delete both answers, and then a neutral person such as myself can post the one true answer.